# SpringSecurity - SecurityContextHolder returning null

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I am using react/spring rest and doing programmatic logout. Login is working fine and when user hits logout, request goes to controller and logs out. Issue i am having is, in logout method inside a controller, i am getting NULL from security context. It looks like a old session is gone. How can i get/retain the user info on SecurityContextHolder.Also, i am using spring-redis for maintaining the session. After successful login, session info is stored on redis but SecurityContext is coming null.

Some code snippets ( logout ):

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
    //session is null
    final Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
   // authentication.getName is null

    if (session != null) {
        session.invalidate();
        session.setMaxInactiveInterval(0);
    }
    SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
    Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
    if (cookies != null) {
        for (Cookie cookie : request.getCookies()) {
            if ("JSESSONID".equals(cookie.getName())) {
                cookie.setMaxAge(0);
                response.addCookie(cookie);
            }
        }
    }`
```

And httpCOnfig:

```
  http
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/api/user/**").hasAnyRole(ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_REGISTERED_USER)
        .antMatchers("/api/admin/**").hasRole(ROLE_ADMIN)
        .antMatchers("/api/public/**").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .csrf().disable()
        .cors()
        .and()
        .httpBasic();
}
```

Comment: `HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);` creates a user sessions.

`final Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();`

This should not give you null if the logout API is configured in your security and you have apt roles to access it

Comment: @YatiSawhney when the request hits the logout end point, it is already null. Do you recommend changes in above configuration. What does this mean 'the logout API is configured in your security' ? I am doing logout from controller not from config.

Comment: logout is some method(handler ) in one of your controllers? Session will not die of its own either you are explicitly calling `session.invalidate()` or the `JSESSIONID` is already being expired

Comment: yeah, first method in the above code snippet is a logout method.

Comment: request.getCookies() see if you have a valid cookie. You got to debug this